# How to prevent browser from refilling form data when navigating back

Tags: php

I have a php form that submits data to a database. When the form has been successfully filled out and the data submitted, the form clears because of the page refresh. When the user hits the back button on the browser, the data comes back.

Is there a php function that will prevent the caching of this data?

Comment: Personally I'd be really mad if I submitted your form, got an HTTP error response and hit [Back] just to see that you thought it would be a nice idea to tamper with my history data and in conclusion forcing me to reenter everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a reliable method, because the behaviour on back varies between browsers. Moreover, if someone has gone back through history, and you change what's happening, you are changing history. The metaphysical "woah!" of that aside, it's not a great idea.

What problem does this cause, apart from issues of from-resubmission? If form-resubmission is a problem then you need to deal with it in the case of a quick double-click on submit too anwyay. Include a hidden nonce value (UUIDs are good), store the nonce with your record of whatever it is the form does, and reject repeated nonces.

Comment: Hi Jon, the issue was the resubmission of the form. I've already contemplated what you are suggesting and just thought I'd ask if pragma no-cache would handle this for me. I generally prefer to take the easier way out, if there is one.

Comment: pragma no-cache is deprecated, so look at the cache-control header. This aside, history records are different to web-caching (quite explicitly stated as such in the standard). Web-caching gives us ways to avoid either having to contact the server for a given URI or else having to download the entire contents. Browser history is a record of the state the browser was previously in, not the same thing at all.

Always give http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt a read over at least a couple of times every year. You can never be over-familiar with it.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem where I am dynamically creating a form and then submitting it, which work great.  But when hitting the back arrow on Android and then fully repopulating what I believe is the form, it doesn't take.  The form data remains what it was on the previous pass, and resubmits it.  It seems like something in the browser is caching the form, yet neither the form nor the previous values appear until after I repopulate them with new values, then it still submits the old values.  I'll ask a question directly too.

Comment: What if you have a simple computer and browser kiosk that is used by clients to submit their info in a form, it basically loops back to a new form each time for each subsequent client, and you don't want the next client to be able to hit back a couple times to see the previous client's information? There are real reasons for wanting to do this.

Comment: @mikato why on earth would you go back rather than going to the form fresh in such a case?

Comment: @JonHanna I personally wouldn't but someone using the kiosk might. (When I say "loops back" I mean there is a link to go back to the form for the next person.) You can't assume they'll behave nicely. This is the same reason you validate input on the server.

Comment: @mikato but if there's a link to go to the form again, it's going to be refreshed again naturally. The only reason to expose the back-history option is precisely because you do want the normal browser behaviour.

Comment: @JonHanna So you're saying that the risk of a second client hitting back is acceptable weighing that against the possibility someone may want to hit back for legit reasons on their own form submission? That is one opinion, maybe I agree, but it doesn't address the issue.

Comment: @mikato If that's a risk, then don't expose back. Why would you have a back-button in such a scenario, unless it was useful and harmless?

Comment: @JonHanna I guess the answer to your question, why would I have a back button, would be because all web browsers have back functionality. You could be a little less condescending. This is really a problem I have and I thought it was relevant to the OP. Ok, so how does one remove back functionality?

Comment: @mikato Maybe I'm misunderstanding "kiosk" here, but I took that as a restricted access set-up in a public place. The only times I've ever seen that, they've been locked down and lacked a right-click or a menu, so the back functionality isn't available.

Comment: @mikato and if I come across as condescending, I apologise.

Comment: @JonHanna Ok I appreciate it and I do appreciate your comments. It would be in a business lobby, near support people. They would fill out their info in a form similar to what's on our site. You're right, I've seen those, and that sounds like something I could use - like at Borders for looking up books.
IE has kiosk mode- http://en.kioskea.net/faq/636-how-to-use-kiosk-mode-with-internet-explorer
Firefox has a kiosk plugin- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/
These aren't secure, alt-left still goes back, but they will probably do. Thanks!

Comment: @JonHanna Actually the Firefox plugin called R-kiosk is better than I thought, even disabling right click and alt-left. Thanks for helping! I think this will work!

Comment: That Firefox plugin is not available for current versions of Firefox I see now. 
Opera Kiosk Mode sounds good, I will try it - http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/

Answer (score 3):

autocomplete="off" in the input fields of your forms?

Comment: I think the issue is not with autocomplete but rather the POSTED data. This data reappears in the form when the back button in the browser is used.